# Port-forwarding fine but not from internal LAN

Tags: portforwarding, openwrt

I have an issue with OpenWRT with port forwarding. T'm doing port- forwarding from WAN to DMZ on port 443. It works fine. Also, when I access from internal LAN to DMZ with private IP it works fine (no port-forwaring involved). But, with my **public IP** from internal LAN it doesn't work. I got a connection refused.

Is there a way to make it works ? (Initially I did port-forwarding only from WAN to DMZ but sometimes I'm at home)

Comment: If you need the public access then set it up that way and even at home use the public ip and not the local ip.

Comment: That's the problem, I set port-forwarding for public access (WAN to DMZ) but at home when I use my ***public IP*** from LAN I got a connection refused.

Comment: Okay, if you have it set up as a DMZ the problem cant be in the router, but you can check. Most if not all routers have logging, check if your connection is being allowed through the router, it should be but check anyway. If its allowed through then your next step will be to check if any software firewalls are installed/ports open for remote hosts. (its possible to allow only local in the system firewall). If firewall(s) are all correct the next would be server logs for the specific server. As its port 443 you will probably want to check that the certificate is installed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to rewrite the destination address in `nat`-`prerouting` chain before forwarding. Further, you need to masquerade the `port forwarded` LAN traffic before sending to DMZ.

Without masquerade, the, packets from DMZ host will be directly sent to LAN client(s). The LAN client(s) will drop these unknown packets as LAN client(s) are expecting the replies come back from Public IP and not DMZ IP.

The easiest way is to masquerade all the LAN traffic to DMZ network like below

```
# Public IP = 208.67.220.220
# Local LAN IP Pool = 192.168.1.0/24
# LAN Interface = 'eth0'
# DMZ Interface = 'eth2'
# DMZ Server IP = 172.16.20.20

iptables -t nat -d 208.67.220.220 -A PREROUTING -i eth0 -j DNAT --to 172.16.20.20
iptables -t nat -s 192.168.1.0/24 -A POSTROUTING -o eth2 -j MASQUERADE
```

One can improvise this to masquerade only port forwarded traffic. I will leave it to the original poster.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the problem. So I add the iptable rules but its not working.

Comment: Ok, now I understand the problem. So I add the iptable rules but its not working. But I'd like to know one thing. With that iptable rule we masquerade all the traffic from LAN to DMZ. But first from LAN I request my public IP and then I can see I receive a RST packet. I think the packet never goes into the DMZ and the router drop it. I think the reason you gave is good but it seems that this iptable don't fix the issue.

Comment: Any updates on this? I'm having the same issue.

Comment: @cristianmiranda you need to share more details before we can help. If you follow my answer carefully you should be able to solve the problem. IP routing needs a return path to work. Basically, there are two steps. First, rewrite the destination path to your DMZ_SERVER_IP in prerouting chain. Second, masquerade the traffic going to DMZ_SERVER_IP to your router IP.